# Node JS TLS server and client aren’t working correctly

Tags: node.js, ssl, web, tcp, insecure-connection

Recently I’ve been trying to make a basic TLC server and client to maybe put on a Rasperry PI. I found an example on [github](https://github.com/ZiCog/node-tls-example) and i modified it so its up to date. My issue is that Node JS keeps saying `unable to verify the first certificate` Even though i generated a new one.

> **note** the certificates and keys are self signed.

Here is my code, I have not the slightest clue as to why its failing because when I set `ServerOptions` As the client options, it just logs `Unsecure connection.`

**Server.js**

```
'use strict';

const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const events = require('events');
const port = 4170;

const ServerOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('agent1-key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('agent1-cert.pem'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('root-cert.pem'), // authority chain for the clients
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

var server = tls.createServer(ServerOptions, (socket) => {
  socket.write('welcome!\n');
  socket.setEncoding('utf8');
  socket.pipe(socket);
})

.on('connection', function(c) {
    console.log('Unsecure connection');
})

.on('secureConnect', function (c) {
    // c.authorized will be true if the client cert presented validates with our CA
    console.log('secure connection\n client authorization Status:', c);
})

.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('server listening on port' + port + '\n');
});`
```

**Client.js**

```
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const events = require('events');
const port = 4170;

const ClientOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('agent2-cert.pem'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('root-cert.pem')
};

const socket = tls.connect(port, ClientOptions, () => {
      console.log('client connected', socket.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');
      process.stdin.pipe(socket);
      process.stdin.resume();
    });
    socket.setEncoding('utf8');
    socket.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
    socket.on('end', () => {
      server.close();
    });
```

So as you probably saw, there is the `ca1-cert.pem`, `agent1-cert.pem`, `agent2-cert.pem`, `agent1-key.pem`, and `agent2-key.pem`. Those are the certificates.

Each of the **cert** files have the beginning and ending

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

And each of the **key** files have the beginning and ending

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

In addition to that, I’m wondering how secure this is because my initial plan is to use this as a login/database server or something that cant be easily hacked into.

Thank you.

**Edit 1**

In the comments, someone said that its possible that the certificate isn’t being verified because of the wrong CA file. I put the CA file in the same place as the “...-cert.pem” files. I’m assuming that’s not the problem though because I talked to my friend, he went over the certificate and key files and said that they’re all good.

Comment: "unable to verify the first certificate" probably means that the system does not have the proper CA in its trust store hence it can not verify the validity of the certificate it sees. So the problem is not directly with the certificate, but with installation of its CA locally.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I have the CA file in the same folder/area as the certificate. Because this is only a test program, I could post a link to the files on github.

Comment: You do not just need them on disk, you need to configure your client to use them. I can not tell you how precisely as I know nothing in NodeJS. But look for some option speaking about "ca certificate" and a path to provide. Then provide the path to your CA files.